# Plotting multiple continuous variables by frequencies together with same scale margin in r

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize my data. All I need is a plot to compare the distribution of the different variables.

I already tried with multi.hist. Actually, that would be enough for me. But the problem is, I cannot manage the margins of the scale to stay the same for each histogram to compare the distributions as it is already trying to fit for each variable.

As well, I have a categorial variable in my data as well (topic 1-5). Maybe there is a good way to visualize this as well but I am not dying if it is not possible so easy.

I tried a lot with ggplot as well but I am rather new to r and could not make anything good yet.

Below you see an example for my data.

Thank you very much in advance :)

My data:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ24M.png)

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Try first converting your data to long format:

```
df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = 1:5, names_to = 'set', values_to = 'sub_means')
```

Then you can do a density plot, either colouring by set and faceting by topic:

```
df2 %>% ggplot(x = sub_means, fill = set) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~topic)
```

Or vice versa:

```
df2 %>% ggplot(x = sub_means, fill = topic) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~set)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run that, it says: 

Error: stat_density() requires an x or y aesthetic.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Error: Attempt to use a variable name of length 0

Comment: What are the colnames of df2?

Comment: topic, set and sub_means

Comment: Apparently that error is often to do with having misplaced backticks/commas/R markdown issues around your code.

Comment: I could not find anything else as there is only your code in the chunk and I tried without other code as well :/